# Polynomial integer coefficients

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Suppose that $\phi(x) = a_nx^n + \cdots + a_0x^0\in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ and let $\phi(x) = p(x)h(x)$ where $p(x),h(x)\in\mathbb{Q}[x]$ and $p(x)$ is monic. Must then $a_n\cdot p(x)$ have integer coefficents.

I am stuck on this problem. My idea is contradiction, suppose that $a_n\cdot p(x)$ doesn't have integer coefficients. Write 
$$
p(x) = \sum_{i=0}^{m-1}b_ix^i + x^m\\  h(x) = \sum_{j=0}^{k}c_jx^j
$$
Then $a_n\phi(x) = a_np(x) h(x) = (a_nx^m+\cdots +a_nb_0)(c_kx^k+\cdots + c_0x^0)$ 
Looking at the leading coefficients,
$$
a_n^2 = a_nc_k
$$ 
This implies $a_n=c_n$. I don't know where to go from here.

Comment: This is interesting, for my learning, could you provide an example?

Comment: You have initially "Must then $a_n\cdot p(x)$ have integer coefficents." and "... suppose that $a_n\cdot p(x)$ doesn't have integer coefficients.". However, in your proof attempt, you have "Then $a_n\phi(x) = a_np(x) h(x) = (a_nx^m+\cdots +a_nb_0)(c_kx^k+\cdots + c_0x^0)$". So, is it $a_n\cdot p(x)$ or $a_n\phi(x)$ that you're asking about and which you are attempting to prove or disprove has integer coefficients?

Comment: I am trying to arrive at a contradiction with assuming that $a_np(x)$ doesn't have integer coefficients.